# Firefox 29: how to get URL/Link preview back

Tags: firefox

With FF version 29 my status bar vanished and I don't see any URL preview: when I hover over a link I want to see the URL associated to it!

Comment: I use Firefox `29.0` too. When I move the mouse over a link, a preview of the URL is displayed at the bottom. If that's not the case, [start Firefox in Safe Mode](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-firefox-issues-using-safe-mode) to see whether you still get the same issue. You can try a [portable version](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable), too. Those steps should provide you enough troubleshooting information; you might then consider [resetting Firefox settings](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/reset-firefox-easily-fix-most-problems).

Answer (score 2):

The link previews are functioning (For example, when I view this page) in Firefox 34.  They appear in the lower-left corner of the window in the same place where they would have been if the status bar still existed.

**But** they don't appear for certain types of links.  Links that invoke Javascript don't seem to have a preview.  I was confused by this and thought the previews were broken for a while after the last upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to fix it by removing Status4Evar and The Puzzle Piece and then restarting Firefox.

You might want to try removing all other add-ons that try and interact with the status bar / add-ons bar.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install an addon called "The Status Bar (Restored)" along with "Status-4-Evar".

Firefox 29 completely removes all addon bar functionality and with it took away the URL preview which not even "Status-4-Evar" seems to put back, this addon puts back the addon bar and Status-4-Evar displays the link preview text within it.

Answer (score 1):

I have the Status-4-Evar but it does not show the link in the status bar, but URL Tooltip (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/url-tooltip) says it will display the destination URL when hovering cursor over a link.

Which should obviously be a default setting (as should <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> toggling between most recently viewed tabs). Thank God for extensions!

Answer (score 0):

For **vimperator users**: I just had to enable the "Liberator statusbar toolbar" by clicking in the menu. What a good feeling to have it back :)

Answer (score -1):

The old status bar is no longer available as part of Firefox 29. However, Mozilla recommends

https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/235283/

as a solution for those of us that want a status bar.

Source: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/what-happened-status-bar

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't answer the question - you get the status bar but not the URL preview thsi way (same with https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/classicthemerestorer/ btw.)